# How do I pass a user id into an Akka system?

Tags: spring, security, authorization, akka

We have a small service using Akka internally to run actions concurrent and in a non-blocking way. Akka is of great value to us, but now I need to add authorization (filtering for search and access restriction on specific objects) to some of the actors. We're using Spring Boot and Spring Security to handle authentication and authorization on the Web container, before transferring most of the work to actors managed by the Akka system. Naively, I thought I could use

String userId = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();

in the actors, but that of course fails because we are on Akka controlled threads. By default, I don't have control over the threads of my Akka system, so there's no thread local security context available.

I see two options:

1. Pass the user id as part of the messages
2. Pass the Spring DelegatingSecurityContextExecutorService to the Akka system via a ExecutionContext

On 1: I can pass the user id with the messages to make it available to the respective actors. However, when the authenticated user id becomes part of a message, how can I protect my actors from getting messages that contain any kind of user id? Is this bad practice or is a Akka system protected against such misuse? Do I need to activate further security on the Akka system?

On 2: I can pass my own ExecutionContext when creating the Akka system. That allows me to pass an instance of Spring's DelegatingSecurityContextExecutorService into it, in the hope that the thread local SecurityContext is being passed along acordingly. Has anybody successfully done that? One issue that comes to my mind here is: What happens when an actor is actually running on a remote machine? The threads there won't have the SecurityContext for sure.

So what's your take on this? Do you see any other options available? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey, how did you solve your problem?